# A vector containing MYSQL_ROWs, passing information to another vector causing issues

Tags: c++, mysql, vector

I am using a method to return a vector. But it seems that in doing so, I lose a bit of information.

The code to generate the vector is as follows:

```
//The printf function, after the while loop is finished, displays the following:
//
// 1 ~/Test/ Folder 0
// 2 ~/Test/ Folder 0
// 4 ~/HelloFromC++ Message 10
// 5 ~/HellowFromC++ Message 10

std::vector<MYSQL_ROW> Database::Query(const char* query, bool hasreturn)
{
MYSQL *connection;
MYSQL_RES *resource;
MYSQL_ROW result;
connection = mysql_init(NULL);

if(!mysql_real_connect(connection, servername, user,
                password, database, 0, socket, 0)) {
                    printf("%s\n", mysql_error(connection));
                }

mysql_query(connection, query);

resource = mysql_use_result(connection);

std::vector<MYSQL_ROW> results (mysql_num_rows(resource));

if(hasreturn)
{
    while((result = mysql_fetch_row(resource))) {
        printf("%s %s %s %s \n",result[0],result[1],result[2],result[3]);
        results.push_back(result);
    }
}

mysql_close(connection);

return results;
}
```

The code which recieves and then displays the vector is as follows:

```
std::vector<MYSQL_ROW> dsMedia = database.Query((char*)("CALL `.Media_Get_List`()"),true);
std::vector<Media> MediaList;

//Convert to media
for(int med = 0; med < dsMedia.size(); med++)
{
    MYSQL_ROW row = dsMedia[med];

    stringstream ss;
    ss << row[0] << row[1] << row[2] << row[3];
    string test = ss.str();

    printf("%s %s %s %s \n",row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3]);
}

//The printf function, after the while loop is finished, displays the following:
//
// * Message 10
// * Message 10
// * Message 10
// * Message 10
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  You didn't place that code in a function body with return type and parameters.  Second, we don't know what `results` is declared as.  Last, you didn't post any calls to functions.  However, more than likely, your issue may have to do with using `char*` and storing the same char pointer value in the individual elements of the vector.

Comment: Sorry, I have just updated the code above.

Comment: Check your vector of MYSQL_ROWs.  Are they the same value?  If they are, then a vector<MYSQL_ROW> isn't going to do the job.  If that is the case, then you need to take the information for each call of `mysql_fetch_row` and copy it to your own struct -- then return a vector of those structs.